# How can I fix import/no-default-export without switching to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, cypress, eslint

I'm trying to put all my selectors in an external JS file and then import them in to my page object when I need them e.g. :

```
Home-page-selectors.js:
    export default {
      headerLinks: 'header a',
      contactUsLink: "header a[href='/contact-us']",
    }
```

Home-page.js includes `import selectors from '../test-data/home-page-data.js'` I can then do things like `cy.get(selectors.headerLinks)`

The problem is when I run my lint tasks I get an error from Home-page-selectors.js saying

> error  Prefer named exports  import/no-default-export

How can I fix this error? I know multiple ways I can do it in TypeScript but unfortunately switching to TS isn't an option due to a number of plugins we use not being compatible.

Comment: export default ... -> export const ... ? You will also need to fix imports from import ... to import  {...}

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example? If I try to change it to export const selectors I get a Webpack Compilation Error.     export const selectors {
      headerLinks: 'header a',
      contactUsLink: "header a[href='/contact-us']",
    }

Comment: In file 1 I do export const selectors = { ... }. In file 2 I do import { selectors } from '...'.    See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export